# Module installation order

Tags: 8, installation

Within my custom module i've got an optional implementation to the dynamic entity reference module: https://www.drupal.org/project/dynamic_entity_reference

When the module exists, I add a DER field to one of my custom tables during the module installation.

The issue i am currently facing is that I can not manipulate the installation order of my module. Within the install hook of my module i am using `module_set_weight("mymodule",1)`.
However this is not effecting the installation order at all when I run `drush config-import` order or `drush site-install --config-dir="/my/conf"`.

Within my `core.extensions.yml` the weight got applied after config export:
`drupal_content_sync: 1`

Answer (score 0):

For me this sounds pretty simple to solve. In your custom module just set a requirement:

```
name: Foo Bar
description: 'Lorem ipsum.'
package: Custom

type: module
core: '8.x'

dependencies:
  - dynamic_entity_reference:dynamic_entity_reference
```

By that you ensure that `dynamic_entity_reference` exists and is enabled when your module gets installed. That's it. Except I misunderstand you and you are instead looking for [`hook_module_implements_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/8.2.x) to change the order of modules calling a certain hook.

Comment: Sadly this is not the thing I want to achieve. dynamic_entity_reference should be a an optional dependency which must not be installed. But if it is installed, you can use some extra functionalities.

Comment: @Sebastian – Then I'd put this into a sub-module instead. Then the user has to decide.

Comment: @Sebastian – Or you make this an option in your modules config page which only can be switched on, if your desired requirements are met.

Comment: Good call, I am going with the submodule :)